# Serialize models like with .values(), but also include ManyToMany related field

Tags: json, django, django-orm

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="books")
```

I'm have pre-existing JavaScript code that works on input that I feed from django like this:

```
json.dumps(list(Book.objects.all().values()), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

`list(Book.objects.all().values())` gives me an array of dictionaries upon which my entire frontend code is based on.

```
[{ "user": 1 }, { ... }, ... ]
```

However, now I've added the tags property. I was expecting to find the `tags` property in my dictionary but there's not: apparently, Django doesn't serialize ManyToMany managers by default.

The offered solution is this:

```
from django.core import serializers
serializers.serialize("json", Book.objects.all())
```

that, however, outputs a dictionary that it's in a completely different form, where all my model properties are inside of a `fields` parameter.

```
[{"model": "Main.book", "pk": 1, "fields": { "user": ... }]
```

How can I have a `tags` field like with `serializers.serialize` while maintaining the `.values()` form? Do I have to re-write my frontend code entirely to use the format of `serializers.serialize` or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Use Django REST Framework which gives you fully customisable serializers.

Comment: Django REST Framework (django-rest-framework) has good serializers for this.